# F# return type of recursive pattern matching

Tags: f#

I just started learning F#, and to improve my skills, I'm trying my hand at the [2019 Advent of Code](https://adventofcode.com/). I'm attempting the first puzzle of day 2, and have gotten stuck. See the rules of day 2 at the bottom.

I think the issue I'm running into is that I don't quite understand how the compiler figures out the return type of a recursive function. See my attempt here:

```ml
let rec intcode (arr: int []) op = // int [] -> int -> int []
    let in1 = op + 1
    let in2 = op + 2
    let out = op + 3
    match arr.[op] with
    | 1 ->
        arr.[arr.[out]] <- arr.[arr.[in1]] + arr.[arr.[in2]]
        intcode arr op+4
    | 2 ->
        arr.[arr.[out]] <- arr.[arr.[in1]] * arr.[arr.[in2]]
        intcode arr op+4
    | 99 -> 
        arr
    | _ -> 
        printfn "Had input operator that was not 1, 2, or 99"
        arr
```

The compiler gives me the function signature commented at the start of the function, `int [] -> int -> int []`.

However, the compiler also tells me that upon trying to return `arr` when matching pattern `99`, `error FS0001: The type 'int' does not match the type 'int []'`.

Is it telling me that it thinks `arr` is an `int`? Or that it thinks the output of the function should be an `int`?

**Rules**

> An Intcode program is a list of integers separated by commas (like 1,0,0,3,99). To run one, start by looking at the first integer (called position 0). Here, you will find an opcode - either 1, 2, or 99. The opcode indicates what to do; for example, 99 means that the program is finished and should immediately halt. Encountering an unknown opcode means something went wrong.
>
> Opcode 1 adds together numbers read from two positions and stores the result in a third position. The three integers immediately after the opcode tell you these three positions - the first two indicate the positions from which you should read the input values, and the third indicates the position at which the output should be stored.
>
> For example, if your Intcode computer encounters 1,10,20,30, it should read the values at positions 10 and 20, add those values, and then overwrite the value at position 30 with their sum.
>
> Opcode 2 works exactly like opcode 1, except it multiplies the two inputs instead of adding them. Again, the three integers after the opcode indicate where the inputs and outputs are, not their values.
>
> Once you're done processing an opcode, move to the next one by stepping forward 4 positions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not (directly) with the type inference, but with [operator precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/symbol-and-operator-reference/#operator-precedence).

```
intcode arr op+4
```

is parsed as

```
(intcode arr op)+4
```

not

```
intcode arr (op+4)
```

because function application has higher precedence than the `+` operator.

Based on the former grouping the compiler infers that the expression must be of type `int` because the outermost expression is an `int` addition.

All you need to do to fix this is add parentheses around`op+4`.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer to the question, but an answer to the original problem.
I thought I'd rewrite it into an immutable version. I hope it's easy to read.

```
let run =
    let rec runr bp memory =
        let read  pos = memory |> Array.item (bp + pos)
        let read' pos = memory |> Array.item (read pos) 
        let write pos value = memory |> Array.mapi (fun i oldv -> if i = pos then value else oldv) 

        let exec op = op (read' 1) (read' 2) |> write (read 3)
        let apply op = runr (bp + 4) (exec op)

        match read 0 with
        | 1  -> apply (+)
        | 2  -> apply (*)
        | 99 -> memory
        | _  -> failwith "Invalid op code"

    runr 0

let result = run [|1;0;0;3;99|]
printf "%A" result
```